# regex removing numbers from column

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to use regex to remove numbers from Column C using the formula below. it works for one cell but not for multiple. I want to apply the formula to the whole c column starting from C7

```
=REGEXREPLACE(C7:C, "[0-9]*\.[0-9]|[0-9]","")
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(C7:C, "[0-9]*\.[0-9]|[0-9]", ))
```

Comment: im getting error "Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in GB6."

Comment: @stacksonoverflow your range is C7:C so you can use this formula in row 1-7 just make sure that column, where you use it, is empty so that formula could roll out for every row automatically. the error you mentioned means that formula attempts to roll out but there is no space to do so hance the error